# Question concerning graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Is it true, that in an undirected single graph, if there are two adjacent cut vertices, the edge connecting those two cut vertices is a cut edge?
I think that this is indeed the case, but I'm struggling a bit with proving this fact. Could someone give me some tips or a general method for approaching graph related proofs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. A simple way to make a vertex $v$ int a cut vertex is to add a leaf adjacent to $v$ and nothing else. Using this construction, you should have no trouble finding a counterexample; the smallest I can think of has $5$ vertices and $5$ edges.

---

Some general tips! Try looking at small cases or small examples and seeing if a statement holds. If it *does* hold, try to think about what makes it true, and if that has to happen in all cases; this could lead you to a proof, or to a counterexample.

Keep in mind equivalent ways to state a property. For this question, it's useful to remember that an edge is a cut edge if and only if it is not part of any cycle.